# Numpy: Fill in a Matrix With a Smaller One FAST

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I'd like to fill in one matrix with copies of another one, like so:

```
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(M):
      matA[:,:,:,i,j] = matB
```

But I have many big dimensions, so I am looking for a faster way.

Comment: What's the shape of `matA` and `matB`?

Comment: Hard to answer without details, including how big is big, how fast is the current solution (and why isn't that fast enough)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could simply get a view into the input with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html)  to get the desired output -

```
matA = np.broadcast_to(matB[:,:,:,None,None], matB.shape + (N,M))
```

Being a view, its virtually free -

```
In [292]: matB = np.random.rand(20,20,20)

In [293]: N,M = 20,20

In [294]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(matB[:,:,:,None,None], matB.shape + (N,M))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.02 µs per loop
```

If you need an output with its own memory space, create a copy with  `matA.copy()`.

---

Alternatively, we could use `np.repeat` -

```
np.repeat(matB[:,:,:,None],N*M,axis=-1).reshape(matB.shape+(N,M))
```